# Not $\sigma$-compact set without axiom of choice

Tags: measure-theory, compactness, axiom-of-choice

> Today in measure theory, we introduced the concept of a $\sigma$-compact set, which is a set which can be expressed as the countable union of compact sets.

Since the set of $\sigma$-compact sets seemed to be very large (I couldn't think of a not $\sigma$-compact set), I asked for a set which is not $\sigma$-compact, but our instructor couldn't come up with a set, which he didn't have to explicitly construct with the axiom of choice, for which we didn't have time.

> My question is if there is such an set which can be constructed without the axiom of choice.

Comment: But this is not about "sets" it's about topology.

Comment: The irrational numbers are famously *not* $\sigma$-compact.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ in the discrete topology is not $\sigma$-compact, as its only compact subsets are finite.

Comment: @Henno: Since this is about measure theory, I expect the question is really in the context of $\Bbb R$ with the standard topology and Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Viktor, compact is a topological notion. Not a measure theoretic one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The axiom of choice is not needed to construct a subset of $\Bbb R$ which is not $\sigma$-compact (which I guess is ultimately what this question is about).

The irrational numbers form such a set, since any compact subset of $\Bbb{R\setminus Q}$ has an empty interior, and therefore any $\sigma$-compact set of irrational numbers is the countable union of closed nowhere dense sets, which means that it is meager. But Baire's theorem shows that the irrational numbers are *not* meager.

(To the initiated, Baire's theorem is provable in $\sf ZF$ when the space is separable, like $\Bbb{R\setminus Q}$ which has $\pi+\Bbb Q$ as a dense subset.)

Answer (score 1):

Note that - in $\mathbb{R}$ at least - a set is $\sigma$-compact only if (indeed, iff) it is the union of countably many closed sets. Such a set is called $F_\sigma$ (or $\Pi^0_2$). A fundamental theorem concerning the topology of $\mathbb{R}$ is the **Baire category theorem**, which states that the intersection of countably many dense open sets is dense. An easy corollary is that no countable dense set can be the intersection of countably many open sets (*exercise!*), and as a consequence the complement of a countable dense set cannot be $F_\sigma$.

So in particular, the set of irrationals is not $\sigma$-compact.

Comment: Well, BCT is generally equivalent to DC. So just saying "Oh BCT shows ..." is not enough to conclude that choice was not needed. But noting that the irrationals are separable is enough to finish the claim.

Comment: I assure BCT is the Baire Category Theorem, but what is DC?

Comment: @Viktor: Dependent Choice. It is a weak form of choice (or a strong form of countable choice).